# Can someone help me in a Lua banking program?

Tags: lua

```
money_on_card = 500
print("Hello! This is your bank, Kudo banking.")
io.write('Press 1 to withdraw, 2 to deposit, 3 to check your money, 4 to leave: ')
local choose = io.read()
if choose == 1 then
    io.write("Enter the amount you want to withdraw: ")
    local withdraw_money = io.read()
    money_on_card = money_on_card - withdraw_money
    while withdraw_money > money_on_card do
        io.write("You don't have enough money. Please enter a valid amount.")
        local withdraw_money = io.read()
        print("Money on your card: ".. money_on_card)
    end
end
if choose == 2 then
    io.write("Enter the amount you want to deposit: ")
    local deposit_money = io.read()
    money_on_card = money_on_card + deposit_money
    print("Money on your card: ".. money_on_card)
end
if choose == 3 then
    print("Money on your card: ".. money_on_card)
end
if choose == 4 then
    print("Thanks for choosing us!")
end
```

I'm running program and entering any number and nothing happens. When I started the code and entering any number, the program closing itself and I can't do anything.

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) Please also edit the title of this question to explain what specific, actionable problem you are having.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation of [io.read](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-io.read), the function is equivalent to [io.input():read](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-file:read) and the behaviour is described as follow:

- Without argument, it will read a line and return a *string*
- With a string argument, the return value will depend

This is an extract of the [Lua 5.4 reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-file:read):

> - **"n"**: reads a numeral and returns it as a float or an integer, following the lexical conventions of Lua. (The numeral may have leading whitespaces and a sign.) This format always reads the longest input sequence that is a valid prefix for a numeral; if that prefix does not form a valid numeral (e.g., an empty string, "0x", or "3.4e-") or it is too long (more than 200 characters), it is discarded and the format returns fail.
> - **"a"**: reads the whole file, starting at the current position. On end of file, it returns the empty string; this format never fails.
> - **"l"**: reads the next line skipping the end of line, returning fail on end of file. This is the default format.
> - **"L"**: reads the next line keeping the end-of-line character (if present), returning fail on end of file.
> - **number**: reads a string with up to this number of bytes, returning fail on end of file. If number is zero, it reads nothing and returns an empty string, or fail on end of file.

---

When we test this function in the Lua interpreter, the behaviour is clear: `io.read("n")` will return a *number*.

```
Lua 5.4.0  Copyright (C) 1994-2020 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> type(io.read())
1
string
> type(io.read("n"))
1
number
```

So I think you need to replace the line `local choose = io.read()` with `local choose = io.read("n")`.